# Is 4-volume element a scalar or a pseudoscalar in special relativity?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, differential-geometry, parity, conventions

In general relativity 4-volume element $\mathrm{d}^4 x = \mathrm{d} x^0\mathrm{d} x^1 \mathrm{d} x^2\mathrm{d} x^3$ is clearly a [pseudoscalar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoscalar) (or [scalar density](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_density)) of weight 1 since it transforms as $\mathrm{d}^4 x \to \mathrm{d}^4 x' = J \,\mathrm{d}^4 x$, with $J$ Jacobian determinant of the coordinates transformation.

In special relativity we consider only Lorentz transformations, which have $J = \pm 1$, so shouldn't $\mathrm{d}^4 x$ be a pseudoscalar also in special relativity?  Landau states ("The Classical Theory of Fields", § 6) that «the element is a scalar: it is obvious that the volume of a portion of four-space is unchanged by a rotation of the coordinate system», but this doesn't proof that $\mathrm{d}^4 x$ is a scalar rather than a pseudoscalar since a pseudoscalar looks like a scalar under a proper rotation of the coordinate system ($J = 1$), differences arise only for an axis inversion ($J = -1$).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I) Consider an arbitrary coordinate transformation

$$x^{\mu}\longrightarrow x^{\prime \nu}~=~f^{\nu}(x).$$

Let

$$J ~:=~\det(\frac{\partial x^{\prime \nu}}{\partial x^{\mu}})$$

denote the corresponding Jacobian.

Traditionally in physics,

1. a **scalar** $\sigma$ transforms as
   $$ \sigma ~\longrightarrow~ \sigma^{\prime}~=~\sigma, $$
2. a **pseudo-scalar** $\sigma$ transforms as
   $$ \sigma ~\longrightarrow~ \sigma^{\prime}~=~{\rm sgn}(J) \sigma,$$
3. a **density** $\rho$ transforms as
   $$ \rho ~\longrightarrow~ \rho^{\prime}~=~\frac{\rho}{J}, $$
4. a **pseudo-density** $\psi$ transforms as
   $$ \psi ~\longrightarrow~ \psi^{\prime}~=~{\rm sgn}(J)\frac{\psi}{J}, $$
5. a **density** $\rho$ of (integer) weight $w$ transforms as
   $$ \rho ~\longrightarrow~ \rho^{\prime}~=~\frac{\rho}{J^w}, $$
6. a **pseudo-density** $\psi$ of (integer) weight $w$ transforms as
   $$ \psi ~\longrightarrow~ \psi^{\prime}~=~{\rm sgn}(J)\frac{\psi}{J^w}. $$

For **tensor**, **pseudo-tensor**, **tensor-density**, **pseudo-tensor-density**, etc, see the [linked](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_density) Wikipedia page.

Examples:

1. On a Lorentzian manifold $(M,g)$ of signature $(-,+,\ldots,+)$, the square root $\sqrt{-\det(g_{\mu\nu})}$ is a density.
2. In General Relativity (GR), the four-form $\mathrm{d} x^0\wedge \mathrm{d} x^1\wedge \mathrm{d} x^2\wedge\mathrm{d} x^3$ transforms as an inverse density, i.e. a density of weight $w=-1$.

II) Within Special Relativity (SR), the Jacobian $J=\pm1 $ is plus/minus one, as OP correctly notes, so that $\mathrm{d} x^0\wedge \mathrm{d} x^1\wedge \mathrm{d} x^2\wedge\mathrm{d} x^3$ transforms as a pseudo-scalar.

III) Landau and Lifshitz (L&L), *The Classical Theory of Fields,* $\S 6$ p. 21 around eq. (6.13), indeed states that the element of integration

$$dx^0 dx^1 dx^2 dx^3 $$

is a scalar. Here are some suggestions:

1. Perhaps L&L are only considering proper [Lorentz transformations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_group) $\Lambda \in SO(3,1)$ where $J=1$ by definition?
2. Perhaps L&L are viewing $dx^0 dx^1 dx^2 dx^3$ not as a four-form but as a manifestly positive infinitesimal volume element, which by definition transforms with the absolute value $|J|$ of the Jacobian $J$?

However, neither of the two above interpretations (1 and 2) seem to fit particularly well with what is said in the rest of $\S 6$, in particular the footnote on p.21.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding Landau's book, I am reading it in the Russian edition, and in that paragraph when he talks about elements of length/area/volume he neglects the pseudo- prefix. The explanation that the 4-volume element is a scalar he explicitly only considers transformations with unit determinant, and it can be easily deduced from what is written that in general, it is a pseudoscalar.