# Difference between vector and pseudo-scalar

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, klein-gordon-equation

In physics, a pseudo-scalar is a quantity that behaves like a scalar, except that it changes sign under a parity inversion such as improper rotations while a true scalar does not.

Can someone show me the graphical picture or illustration that how a scalar changes under rotations?

**Why we can't say it as vector, if just the sign of the quantity changes? What is the fundamental difference between a vector and pseudo-scalar?**

**Why is the Klein-Gordon equation an equation of motion for a pseudo-scalar field?**

Comment: More on pseudo-tensors: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/32159/2451

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- A scalar is invariant under rotation
- A pseudo-scalar is also invariant under a proper rotation but changes sign with parity.
- A vector is not invariant under a general rotation (only invariant under rotation around a rotational axis parallel to the vector), but rather transforms according to multiplication with a rotation matrix.