# Derivation of the volume element (which uses the metric tensor)?

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus

I have often seen $\sqrt{-g}$ in integrals, especially actions, where $g=\mathrm{det}(g_{\mu \nu})$. Does anyone know of a derivation that shows that this is indeed the [volume element](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_tensor_%28general_relativity%29#Volume) which must be utilized? I have searched online, but all the literature I have encountered assumes you accept it as the volume element.

Comment: Towards the end of Chapter 2 of Sean Carroll's lecture notes: http://preposterousuniverse.com/grnotes/

Comment: Doesn't the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_element) explain it sufficiently?  It seems to have a nice simple example too.

Answer (score 3):

I) Pragmatically speaking, the most important property of $\sqrt{-g}$ for model building purposes, is *not* per se the fact that $\sqrt{-g}d^{4}x$ measures the volume element of a 4-dimensional [Parallelepiped](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelepiped) with infinitesimal edges $dx^0, \ldots, dx^3$.

II) A more important property is that $\sqrt{-g}d^{4}x$ transforms as a **scalar** (i.e. is invariant) under general coordinate transformations 
$$x^{\prime \mu} ~=~ f^{\mu}(x^0 , \ldots, x^3).$$ 
In more detail, the factor $\sqrt{-g}$ transforms as a **density** under general coordinate transformations, cf. also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/32187/2451) Phys.SE answer.

III) *Example:* The [Einstein-Hilbert action](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein%E2%80%93Hilbert_action)

$$S_{EH}[g]~:=~\int R \sqrt{-g}d^{4}x$$

is invariant under change of coordinates, because the scalar curvature $R$ and  volume element $\sqrt{-g}d^{4}x$ are both invariant under general coordinate transformations. Thus the action $S_{EH}[g]$ is a geometric quantity that doesn't depend on the choice or coordinates.

IV) The factor $\sqrt{-g}$ is the so-called **canonical density** on a [Lorentzian manifold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-Riemannian_manifold). If the Lorentzian manifold is endowed with another density $\rho$, one could in principle use that to build actions and get interesting theories.

V) Finally let us mention that on a [symplectic manifold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_manifold) $(M,\omega)$, the canonical density is instead given by the [Pfaffian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pfaffian)

$$ {\rm pf}(\omega_{ij}) $$

of the symplectic matrix $\omega_{ij}$.

Comment: Another thing one could mention is that given an (ordered) basis of orthonormal 1-forms $\theta_i$ this volume form can be written as $\theta_1 \wedge \theta_2 \wedge \dots \wedge \theta_n$ up to sign (which depends on choice of orientation and the signature of the metric)