# What is pseudo-tensor?

Tags: differential-geometry, relativity, tensor-calculus, conventions, definition

What is the [pseudo-tensor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudotensor) in relativity?
How do we transform tensor and pseudo-tensor under parity?

Comment: When you say 'the' pseudotensor, do you mean a specific one? There's more than one, you know.

Comment: So, Can we write for a vector as a tensor $V^a$, $P(V^a)=V^a$ for $a=0,1,2,3$, I think we can not.

Comment: More on pseudo-tensors: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/32159/2451

Answer (score 4):

From the [Wikipedia page on pseudotensors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudotensor),

> a pseudotensor is usually a quantity that transforms like a tensor under an orientation-preserving coordinate transformation (e.g., a proper rotation), but additionally changes sign under an orientation reversing coordinate transformation (e.g., an improper rotation, which is a transformation that can be expressed as a proper rotation followed by reflection).

The action of parity on a tensor or pseudotensor depends on the number of indices it has (i.e. its tensor rank):

- Tensors of odd rank (e.g. vectors) reverse sign under parity.
- Tensors of even rank (e.g. scalars, linear transformations, bivectors, metrics) retain their sign under parity.
- Pseudotensors of odd rank (e.g. pseudovectors) retain their sign under parity.
- Pseudotensors of even rank (e.g. pseudoscalars) reverse sign under parity.

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: @user55944 the determinant of the metric, $g$

Comment: [Yes.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudotensor#Examples)

Comment: ok!, What about $g_{ab}$, $R_{ab}$, $\epsilon_{abcd}$? How we kow whether they are tensor or pseudo tensor?

Comment: The fully antisymmetric one, like $\epsilon$, is the best example of the pseudotensor. Unless something else is explicitly written using such an epsilon and other things that are ordinary tensors, it is probably an ordinary tensor, like g and R. So you de facto count the number of epsilon factors in the most appropriate "definition" of the tensor. If the number is odd, then it is  a pseudotensor, even is tensor.

Comment: What about Einstein-Hilbert action? $L_{E-H}= R\sqrt{-g}d^4x $ How can I show that is parity invariant?

Comment: dear Emilio thanks for reply. I think we can not write also  $P(V^a)=-V^a$ for a=0,1,2,3. It is corect for only i=1,2,3

Comment: [Yes.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_(physics))

Answer (score 3):

The word "pseudotensor" is used in the sense that Emilio Pisanty mentioned, but it also has a completely different and fairly common meaning in general relativity: a multidimensional array of numbers indexed by spacetime coordinates that doesn't transform as a tensor. [Energy pseudotensors](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/Relativity/GR/energy_gr.html) are an example. Both of these meanings are mentioned in the Wikipedia article.