# Pseudotensor in different dimensions

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, conventions, definition

In this topic [What is pseudo-tensor?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/129417/) one answer was the next:
The action of parity on a tensor or pseudotensor depends on the number of indices it has (i.e. its tensor rank):

The action of parity on a tensor or pseudotensor depends on the number of indices it has (i.e. its tensor rank):

- Tensors of odd rank (e.g. vectors) reverse sign under parity.
- Tensors of even rank (e.g. scalars, linear transformations, bivectors, metrics) retain their sign under parity.
- Pseudotensors of odd rank (e.g. pseudovectors) retain their sign under parity.
- Pseudotensors of even rank (e.g. pseudoscalars) reverse sign under parity.

But I don't understand one thing. Is that statement only for Euclidean three dimensions? I attempted understand it myself. And it is my thoughts. Pseudotensor is determined as:
$\hat{P}^{i_1\ldots i_q}_{\,j_1\ldots j_p} =
(-1)^A A^{i_1} {}_{k_1}\cdots A^{i_q} {}_{k_q}
B^{l_1} {}_{j_1}\cdots B^{l_p} {}_{j_p}
P^{k_1\ldots k_q}_{l_1\ldots l_p} $

where $(-1)^A = \mathrm{sign}(\det(A^{i_q} {}_{k_q})) = \pm{1}$.

Let's consider a pseudovector in Euclidean three dimensions. Then $\det(A^{i_q} {}_{k_q})$ is
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & -1 & 0 \\ 
0 &  0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}
And $(-1)^A=-1$

Let's consider a pseudovector in Euclidean three dimensions. Then $\det(A^{i_q} {}_{k_q})$ is
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & -1 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 &  0 & -1 &0 \\
0 &  0 & 0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}
And $(-1)^A=1$

Let's consider a pseudovector in Minkovski space. Then $\det(A^{i_q} {}_{k_q})$ is
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & -1 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 &  0 & -1 &0 \\
0 &  0 & 0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}
And $(-1)^A=-1$

am I right?

Comment: More on [pseudo-tensors](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+pseudo*+tensor*).

Comment: Note that if $\det A = +1$ then $A$ is not a parity transformation. So for instance, the matrix $\mathrm{diag}(-1,-1,-1,-1)$ is in fact a rotation in four dimensions.